# Curving lines around circles

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

its hard to desribe this so I have added an image, how does one make a set of lines go around a circle without touching the circle, I have tried using different effects and warps but just can't seem to wrap my head around it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a step blend, and then a transform effect to reflect it.

An example

[image]

[image]